# Networkx tools in Python

Tags: python, networkx

Hi i am still quite new to networkx python.
[image]
does anyone know how i can get all of the intersection?
Intersection nodes are the red circled. This is for undirected Graph, I would also very keen to know if there is also a way to get intersection for directed graph

Once i got the intersection, I also would like to get the start and the end node. the reason is I wanted to put different group to the path (from start node to end node)
Can I achieve this result too :<
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If with intersections you mean nodes with more than two neighbors than you can use that exact logic like

```
intersections = [node for node in G.nodes() if len(list(G.neighbors(node)))>2]
H = G.copy()
H.remove_nodes_from(intersections)
components = nx.connected_components(H)
```

For "spotting" intersection you can issue them an attribute like this:

```
intersections_subgraph = nx.subgraph(G, intersetions)
nx.set_node_attributes(intersections_subgraph, True, 'intersection')
```

Adding intersections back into the sections should works by looping through the intersections neighbors and adding the intersection to the section the neighbors are in.

For sorting I would loop through the section to find a start point (only one edge/neighbor) and then move from node to node. Note that sets are always unordered so you will have to switch over to an ordered structure like a list.

Ill leave implementing those to you

Comment: Hey thanks for thatt, I am able to get the intersection :D. But then I got another challenge on how to group them starting from the start node to intersection. (I added more details to my question) do you have any idea :<

Comment: @cyntha something like this?

Comment: OMG exactlyy !! T.T How could think of that thanksssss.
If you dont mind , 
1. could i ask how to include the intersection to all of the group and then easily spot the intersection (in case I would like to remove for later on)
2. Also, right now some of the path in the components for example is not in the correct order . For example :
{'FENWICK STREET', 'STEVENS STREET', 'NEWCOMBE STREET', 'DRYSDALE STREET'}
while it should be { 'STEVENS STREET', 'FENWICK STREET','NEWCOMBE STREET', 'DRYSDALE STREET'} .
sorry for too much question :|

Comment: I know that  {'FENWICK STREET', 'STEVENS STREET', 'NEWCOMBE STREET', 'DRYSDALE STREET'}  is not in the correct order because I have added STEVENS  STREET in the graph first, so when printing the components, it is not in order....:/ thank you so much in advance